# Show measure of $\liminf$ is less than $\liminf$ of measure (Proof Verification)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

If $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space and {$E_j$}, j=1 ,2....$\infty$.$\subset$ M, then $\mu$ (lim inf $E_j$) $\leq$ lim inf $\mu(E_j)$

Proof:
$\mu(\liminf E_j)=\mu(\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty} E_j) \right) = \lim_{k\to\infty}\mu(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}( E_j))=\liminf_{k\to\infty}\mu(\bigcap_{j=k}^{\infty}( E_j))\leq\liminf_{k\to\infty}\mu( E_j)$.

Should I be taking the limit as k approaches infinity or should I be taking the limit as j approaches infinity? I'm not sure whether I'm correct.  I'm using the property continuity from below.  Please let me know whether I should taking limit as j approaches infinity or k approaches infinity. Thanks

Comment: Seems that you should write $$  \lim_k \color{red}{\mu\left(\bigcap_{j=k}^\infty E_j\right)}, $$ since $\mu(E_j)$ are numbers, you cannot take the intersection of them.

Comment: @xbh so should it be $lim_k$ or $lim_ j$

Comment: Please check your post first. I am not sure i can get the point of your proof.

Comment: @xbh good catch, that was a typo ill fix, but I'm still concerned about over k or over j

Comment: @xbh will fix right now

Comment: @xbh my post is fixed. let me know whether I should be taking the limit as k approaches infinity or as j approaches infinity

Comment: You could write your last $E_j$ as $E_k$, cause $\cap_k^\infty E_j \subset E_t  $ for all $t \geqslant k$, particularly for $E_k$. Then your expression only involves $k$, problem solved.

Comment: @xbh thanks so it is correct that i put k approaches infinity? i just want to make everything is correct

Comment: Seems okay, if each of your steps could be justified.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who's curious about the answer to kemb's main question, it is fine to use "k" in the limit. Reason? Recall by the basic property of set intersection, we can deduce that $\bigcap_{j=k }^{\infty} (E_{j}) \subseteq E_{j}$ given any $j\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, it necessarily must follow from subadditivity that, indeed, $\limsup_{k \to \infty} \mu (\bigcap_{j=k }^{\infty} (E_{j})) \leq \mu (\bigcap_{j=k }^{\infty} (E_{j})) $$\leq \mu (E_{j}) = \limsup_{k \to \infty} \mu (E_{j})$.